# Subaccount SID & Token Retrieval

Tags: php, twilio, sid

I currently am developing a PHP application for a large amount of users using the Twilio API.

I was successful in allowing users to login and create a subaccount, but what I found I need to do in order for them to be able to individually purchase their own numbers is dynamically pull each subaccount SID & Access token based on whatever account is currently logged in (or so I think this is the way of going about it).

From what I can see in the [API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts), it doesn't seem like there's a straightforward way of doing this.

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend that when you sign up a user and create a subaccount for them that you save the subaccount's SID and auth token to a local database of yours. Then, when a user tries to buy a phone number you can pull their credentials from the database, initialise a REST client using the helper library using the credentials and make calls to the API on behalf of the subaccount.

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you set the FriendlyName to match you member's ID or linkable name; you can pull it from Twilio like:

```
$client = new Client($masterSID, $masterToken);
$subAccounts = $client->api->accounts->read(
        array("friendlyName" => "Member:1")
);
$subAccount = array_pop($subAccounts);
echo $subAccount->sid . "\r\n";
echo $subAccount->authToken . "\r\n";
echo $subAccount->status;
```